# ibmq_qasm_simulator from IBMQ provider and qasm_simulator from Aer provider gives different results

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience

I'm running an experiment first on `qasm_simulator` backend from `Aer` provider and the most frequent result is the correct one with the minimal energy value. Then I'm running the same experiment with the same configuration and parameter set on `ibmq_qasm_simulator` backend from `IBMQ` provider and got different results (don't reach minimal energy value). What is the reason for this behavior?

Comment: You should post the code so we can better understand the issue.

Comment: These backends should in most cases return very similar results? The code of the experiment is quite complex and hard to understand, therefore my question is in general what are the differences of these backends and what could be the reason for different results :)

Comment: The ibmq simulator uses the Aer code internally, which is why I wanted to see the difference in outputs.

Comment: ok :) these are results from qasm_simulator: `{"0010010101": 61, "1010010101": 2, "1000010101": 70, "1100010101": 8, "0000010101": 799, "0110010101": 2, "0100010101": 57, "1000001110": 1}` , these from ibmq_qasm_simulator: `{"0110010101": 1, "0000010101": 52, "0100010101": 368, "0010011100": 366, "0100011100": 1, "1010010101": 3, "0110011100": 153, "1000010101": 4, "1110011100": 10, "1100010101": 16, "1010011100": 25, "0000011100": 1}`. The lowest energy is for configuration: `"0000010101"`. On `qasm_simulator` this config got **799** and in `ibmq_qasm_simulator` this config got only **52**.